# How to scrape a table using BeautifulSoup as I couldn't select the table id attribute?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new about HTML and web scraping. I've been trying to scrape the table elements from the following link:

https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Hong-Kong-and-Mainland-Market-Highlights?sc_lang=en#select3=0&select2=2&select1=28

What I want to do is to extract elements such as "Total turnover", "Total Market capitalization" etc. As I inspect, all these elements lie in `<div class="table-container fixed-freeze-tb-parent" id="Tbl__0">`.

What puzzled me was when I created the BeautifulSoup object and retrieved the text file using

```
turn180329 = requests.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Hong-Kong-and-Mainland-Market-Highlights?sc_lang=en#select3=0&select2=2&select1=28')
turnsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(turn180329.text,'lxml')`

`file180329 = open('180329.txt','wb')
for char in turn180329.iter_content(1000000):
    file180329.write(char)
file180329.close()
```

I could select `div[class="table-container fixed-freeze-tb-parent"]` to return the `div` element but returned nothing when I select the `id="tbl__0"` using

`turn_table = turnsoup.find_all('#tbl__0.table-container fixed-freeze-tb-parent')`

to extract any desired table elements.

A million appreciation and thanks to anyone who could help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Juan Javier Santos Ochoa says, the browser actually sends another URL, for which the server responds with JSON data. Here's the code part to complement his answer.

The date part (`TDD=29`, `TMM=3`, `TYYYY=2018`) in this URL can be modified to get results of a different day:

```
url = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/ws/Highlightsearch.asmx/GetData?LangCode=en&TDD=29&TMM=3&TYYYY=2018'
```

Thanks to @Keyur Potdar for pointing out that headers need not be sent.

Here's the line that sends the request and fetches the JSON:

```
r = requests.get(url)
d = r.json()
```

And, here's the result:

```
# Turnover (Mil. shares) - Main Board, GEM
>>> print(d['data'][9]['td'][1])
['232,780', '1,769']
```

**Edit:**

- You can use an online service like [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/) to understand the structure of a JSON object.

Comment: No headers are required for this URL. Also, I think you should add the line `d = r.json()` in the code (which I guess you're probably using; and if not, please use this built-in JSON parser).

Answer (score 1):

That is because the data in the table is not in the html source when you do a request. You can use [developers tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) of your browser and inspect the requests that the website does. In this case, I can detect that the website does a request to get the data to the url: https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/ws/Highlightsearch.asmx/GetData?LangCode=en&TDD=29&TMM=3&TYYYY=2018&_=1522759817885

This returns the data of the table in a json format.

Comment: Your answer would be more *complete* if you add the code to show how to scrape data from the URL you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the site is dynamic i.e a front-end script updates the DOM with values from the backend when opened by the browser. To scrape from a dynamic site, you will need to use a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Hong-Kong-and-Mainland-Market-Highlights?sc_lang=en#select3=0&select2=2&select1=28')
new_data = [[b.text for b in i.find_all('td')] for i in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all('tr')][2:-2]
```

Output:

```
[[u'No. of listed companies', u'1,827', u'352', u'1,406', u'51', u'2,096', u'49'], [u'No. of listed H shares', u'230', u'24', u'n.a.', u'n.a.', u'n.a.', u'n.a.'], [u'No. of listed red-chips stocks', u'158', u'6', u'n.a.', u'n.a.', u'n.a.', u'n.a.'], [u'Total no. of listed securities', u'13,527', u'353', u'n.a.', u'n.a.', u'n.a.', u'n.a.'], [u'Total market capitalisation(Bil. dollars)', u'HKD 34,139', u'HKD 264', u'RMB 32,376', u'RMB 91', u'RMB 23,008', u'RMB 74'], [u'Total negotiable capitalisation (Bil. dollars)', u'n.a.', u'n.a.', u'RMB 27,500', u'RMB 91', u'RMB 16,580', u'RMB 73'], [u'Average P/E ratio (Times)', u'12.42', u'42.23', u'17.72', u'21.42', u'32.89', u'11.06'], [u'Total turnover (Mil. shares)', u'232,780', u'1,769', u'17,027', u'22', u'19,244', u'13'], [u'Total turnover (Mil. dollars)', u'HKD 137,287', u'HKD 821', u'RMB 210,972', u'RMB 158', u'RMB 268,838', u'RMB 72'], [u'Total market turnover(Mil. dollars)', u'HKD 138,108', u'RMB 213,189', u'RMB 268,910']]
```